# how to display the same brands products at product detail page in bigcommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

i want to display the same brand products on products detail page in big-commerce how to show it i want the global variable to show it also  i want to show the featured products at product details page how to do it in big-commerce any help appreciated

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think you can display "same brand products" easily. You could implement it via manually defined "related products", but that would be hard to manage in a long run.
2. This is simple one. Just add `%%Panel.HomeFeaturedProducts%%` to your `ProductDetails.html` (you can do it in Design Mode - just append `/admin/designmode.php?ToDo=editFile&File=Panels/ProductDetails.html` to your Store URL.

End of your `Panels/ProductDetails.html` will afterwards look something like this:
[image]